# Dummy camera clears the depth buffer

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, blit, zbuffer

I have a camera set up to blit a texture to the screen. The camera is set to Don't Clear and has nothing in the Culling Mask.
The blit is done with a basic unlit shader with ZWrite Off and ZTest Always. The texture to be blitted is mainly completely transparent.

There are 2 problems.

Firstly, if I set the Viewport Rect on the camera to 0,0,1,1 It draws black across the whole screen. No idea why. To solve this I set it to 0, 0, 0.9999, 0.9999. For some reason this works but...

Secondly, the blit works fine but the camera clears the depth buffer. Another camera has already drawn the ground and I need to draw the foreground but anything that lies behind the ground is drawn on top of it.

Anyone have any idea why the thing with the Viewport Rect is happenening?

But more importantly, how do I stop the dummy camera from clearing the depth buffer?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have forgotten to ask the question.

Comment: I thought it was self evident but I've edited for clarity.

Comment: The problem was clear, but what you wanted to be done about it wasn't. I don't have any good ideas regarding the viewport. Maybe the resolution is strange or the texture is setup wrong. I've had a bit of experience with blit before,but have never gotten the depth buffer values. It seems like they are deleted as soon as the image is rendered,

Comment: It's actually the screen depth buffer that that gets cleared. This despite the camera being set to "Don't Clear".